# ¿Cómo importar fonts a mi proyecto android?

Tags: android, android-studio

He intentado con este método

```
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/euphoria.ttf");
    tv.setTypeface(typeface);
```

y no logro, se cae la aplicación al abrirla, otra cosa es que cuando arrastro la fuente me dice "la fila fue cargada en una codificación errónea"[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: puedes intentar con esta liga https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html ahora puedes agregar fonts directamente al directorio res. saludos

Comment: Jesus, no debes modificar el archivo .ttf porque puedes dejarlo corrupto. Revisaste que más muestra el LogCat?

Comment: no lo modifico, cuando lo importo se abre solo

Answer (score 0):

Una opción para cargar una fuente a una vista se realiza precisamente como lo haces, la fuente se agrega en el folder `/assets` por ejemplo:

```
//Obtiene referencia del TextView.
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
//Crea un TypeFace con el archivo de la fuente.
Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/euphoria.ttf");
//Asigna el tipo de fuente al TextView.
tv.setTypeface(typeFace);
```

En el ejemplo anterior el archivo .ttf se encuentra en:

```
/assets/fonts/euphoria.ttf
```

Aquí el problema es que probablemente tu archivo .ttf esta corrupto o dañado, si lo abres no debes modificar el contenido!.

Otra forma es agregar directamente la definición de la fuente en el .xml pero funciona desde la API 14 (android 4.0) y es necesaria la support library versión 26 o posterior ( configurar en `build.gradle`).

Debes agregar tu archivo de tipo de fuente dentro del folder `/res/font`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y cargarla dentro de tu vista mediante la propiedad `android:fontFamily` :

```
<TextView
        android:id"@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/lobster"/>
```

Revisa la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html).